# How to create a sequence of intervals for allocating a value

Tags: r, session, time, intervals, xts

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to split seconds between session start and end time into 15 minute intervals to I can show the seconds and multiple of the bitrate in each interval.

Here is some sample data:

`df <- structure(list(username = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("user1", "user2", "user3", 
"user4", "user5", "user6", "user7", "user8", 
"user9"), class = "factor"), bitrate = structure(c(3500000, 7000000, 
3500000, 3500000, 3500000, 7000000, 3500000, 7000000, 3500000, 7000000), class = "numeric"), 
    start = structure(c(1322700567, 1322700984, 1322700646, 1322700883, 
    1322700042, 1322700073, 1322700547, 1322700794, 1322700694, 
    1322700934), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    end = structure(c(1322700766, 1322701250, 1322700945, 1322701270, 
    1322701284, 1322706303, 1322701781, 1322702307, 1322701600, 
    1322701224), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("username", 
"birate", "start", "end"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")`

```
      username  birate               start                 end
1     user1 3500000 2011-12-01 01:49:27 2011-12-01 01:52:46
2     user2 7000000 2011-12-01 01:56:24 2011-12-01 02:00:50
3     user3 3500000 2011-12-01 01:50:46 2011-12-01 01:55:45
4     user4 3500000 2011-12-01 01:54:43 2011-12-01 02:01:10
5     user5 3500000 2011-12-01 01:40:42 2011-12-01 02:01:24
6     user6 7000000 2011-12-01 01:41:13 2011-12-01 03:25:03
7     user7 3500000 2011-12-01 01:49:07 2011-12-01 02:09:41
8     user8 7000000 2011-12-01 01:53:14 2011-12-01 02:18:27
9     user9 3500000 2011-12-01 01:51:34 2011-12-01 02:06:40
10    user9 7000000 2011-12-01 01:55:34 2011-12-01 02:00:24
```

>

Ideally I want to do this in R if possible, only needs to be for 1 calendar day, with either showing the seconds in a vector or allocating the bitrate vector as a multiple of the seconds, so for example with seconds:

```
session 01:30   01:45   02:00   02:15   02:30  etc.
   1        0      199      0       0       0  etc.
   2        0      266      0       0       0  etc.
  10        0      306      24      0       0  etc.
```

I was thinking either a sequence by minute or perhaps using xts with align time might be the best approach.

Comment: Can you explain where your "clock" starts?  I don't see any relationship between the `start` times and the values in `01:00`

Comment: There is no relationship it was just an example of what the desired output would look like.  I'll go back and edit it so the example output lines up. Thanks

Comment: Corrected to line up the output example.

Comment: Apologies for the late changes and rushed formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain this code is exactly what you want to do, but I hope it helps move you in the desired direction.

```
fun <- function(i, d) {
  idx <- seq(d$start[i],d$end[i],1)    # create sequence for index
  dat <- rep(d$birate[i],length(idx))  # create data over sequence
  xts(dat, idx, dimnames=list(NULL,d$username[i]))  # xts object
}

# loop over each row and put each row into its own xts object
xl <- lapply(1:NROW(df), fun, d=df)
# merge all the xts objects
xx <- do.call(merge, xl)
# apply a function (e.g. colMeans) to each 15-minute period
xa <- period.apply(xx, endpoints(xx, 'minutes', 15), colMeans, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for thanks very much joshua ... the only change i made was to divide xa by 900 seconds to get the proportional bitrate in the interval and to transform xa and cbind it back to df ... i've yet to see how it scales over a few million rows.